# Some error about calling a .mexw64 file in Matlab code

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

Recently,I used Mex to compile some `.cpp` file into `.mexw64`.
The following is the specific process:

1)I put `mexResize.cpp` `MxArray.cpp` and `MxArray.h` into a folder;

2)Then I run a `make.m` and get a `mexResize.mexw64` in the folder above:
[Command window of `matlab`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XMB2.jpg)

3)Finally I use `mexResize.mexw64` in my `matlab` code:

```
img1 = mexResize(img,[100,100]);
```

However,I met the error like the following:
[Error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZrso.jpg)

There are some Chinese sentences above,I try to translate them as following:

1. "MEX The file appears unexpected standard exceptions"
2. "Error test (line 3)"

Apologize for my limited English.

Comment: we need more information. Can you show us your code? Is there a way you can locate the EXACT error it would give in english?

Comment: However what I see in your image is that the error is somewhere when calling `cv::merge`. You may be calling this explicityl or just using some ioenCV function that calls it. We probably need the whole code to debug

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.The code is too long to paste here.I don't know which is the best method to show the code for you.I just put the code on my cloud.Here is the link:[code](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1gfCxuZh) BTW:I use matlab2014a+VS2013+opencv3.1